# How to setup chatter that users can be notified of new feeds etc on their mobile phone?

Tags: chatter

I am given the task to get about 50 users setup in chatter but they will be on the move so they need to be notified about new topics and feeds via email or whatever. It is assumed that unless they are notified that there is something for them, they won't just check chatter on their own. These users are contacts but we'd love it if they didn't have to login to SF but rather just some how be able to check chatter groups that they are connected to.

Is any of this doable and how to get it set up?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create `chatter user` for them. Now whenever you mention them or post any update Salesforce will automatically send them update email. You can set the email priority to daily or per post so that they will get their notification.

Because you want to notify them individually so in this case you need to create user for them.

**Update:** You need to update their notification setting as well. Because by default it is set to Daily digests you need to change this to per post.

To update user notification setting you can use Data Loader to mass update the Email Notification Preference of the group members or .

- From your personal settings, enter Chatter in the Quick Find box,
  then select Chatter Email Settings or Email Notifications—whichever
  one appears. Or, from any group page, click Email Me... | Email
  Settings.

Or you can take help from reference

1. [Reference 1](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000htR2AAI)
2. [Reference 2](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=collab_email_notify.htm&language=en)
3. [Reference 3](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=collab_email_digest.htm&language=en_US)

Comment: I created a chatter external user. I put it in a group and then posted something in the group. The user didn't get an email notification that something was posted to the group. Did it do this right? Would it have mattered if it was a chatter free user?

Comment: In the user You also need to update notification setting.

Comment: @ApexN-u-b  check my updated answer.

Comment: You answered my question thanks. I didn't get an email but I have a strong feeling that it is related to the fact that I am testing this in sandbox.